# How does concurrency work in Node.js + Express application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

(Solution found)

I would like to start my question with code example:

```
var express = require('express');
var customModule = require('./custom-module');

var app = express();

// Page A
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    customModule.doHeavyOperation(25, function(result) {
        res.send('Page A, number = ' + result);
    });
});

// Page B
app.get('/b', function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send('Page B');
});

app.listen(8082);
```

For **Page A** call doHeavyOperation() which performs some actions and when they are done, it runs my callback which sends some information to user.

```
cutsom-module.js:

exports.doHeavyOperation = function(number, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
        number++;
    }
    callback(number);
};
```

For doHeavyOperation() it takes ~5 seconds to perform it's logic and to call my callback. When I open in my browser two pages: localhost:8082/a and localhost:8082/b, the second page needs to wait until the first one will load. That means that requests are handled not concurrently.

Instead of doHeavyOperation there can be any other function which will freeze my clients while they try to use my web application. For example, I may want to process some big images that my user upload, to apply some filters on them, etc. It can take 1-3 seconds. So if there will be 100 people using my website at the same time, it will cause big problems.

For example, Apache + PHP deals with this situation pretty good. While script a.php performs some actions, script b.php can be loaded without problems.

How to achieve this behaviour in Node.js + Express?

================================================================================

Accodring to the kamituel's comment, my decidion was to spawn new process for performing "Heavy" calculations and return the result to the parent process. Now application works as I wanted.

I modified my code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// Page A
app.get('/a', function(req, res) {
    // Creating child process
    var child = require('child_process').fork('custom-module.js');
    // Sending value
    child.send(25);
    // Receiving result
    child.on('message', function(result) {
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.send('Page A, number = ' + result);
    });
});

// Page B
app.get('/b', function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send('Page B');
});

app.listen(8082);
```

custom-module.js:

```
function doHeavyOperation(number, callback) {
    for (var i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
        number++;
    }
    callback(number);
};

process.on('message', function(number) {
    doHeavyOperation(number, function(result) {
        process.send(result);
    });
});
```

More info about child_process [here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript (so Node.js as well) uses one main thread for (almost) all of the JS code you write. This means that if you have some long running task (like a huge loop as in your example), this task will block execution of other code (i.e. callbacks).

What can you do about that?

- Break the loop into smaller pieces, and yield the control occasionally (i.e. using setTimeout/nextTick or similar). I.e. you can iterate from 0 to 1000, then do the next 1000 of the loop iterations on the next tick and so on.
- spawn a new process and handle the heavy task there. Since new process will be outside of Node.js itself, it will not block it.